# How to iterate python list in the SIMILARITY() postgres function

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to pass a list, but it only works without the SIMILARITY function

```
  titles = ['THEME', 'TRIMP', 'RING']

  query = """SELECT * FROM invoice t WHERE t.title = ANY(:ts);"""

  invoices = engine.execute(text(query), ts=titles)
```

I want to do is something like that, that can receive `list`

I try to do is `fuzzystrmatch`

`SIMILARITY(title, ['THEME', 'TRIMP', 'RING'])`

Answer (score 0):

SIMILARITY doesn't yield a boolean, so can't be used like that.  If you instead want to use the `%` operator (which applies predetermined cutoff to 1-SIMILARITY), just replace `=` in your existing query with `%`.

Comment: I already updated the question, I want to make fuzzystrmatch with a list